# jinja2 variable inside a variable

Tags: dictionary, jinja2

I am passing a dictionary to a template.

```
dict road_len = {"US_NEWYORK_MAIN":24,
            "US_BOSTON_WALL":18,
            "FRANCE_PARIS_RUE":9,
            "MEXICO_CABOS_STILL":8}

file_handle = output.txt
env.globals.update(country = "MEXICO")
env.globals.update(city = "CABOS")
env.globals.update(street = "STILL")
file_handle.write(env.get_template(template.txt).render(road_len=road_len)))
```

```
template.txt

This is a road length is: {{road_len["{{country}}_{{city}}_{{street}}"]}}
```

```
Expected output.txt
This is a road length is: 8
```

But this does not work as nested variable substitution are not allowed.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

You never nest Jinja `{{..}}` markers. You're **already** inside a template context, so if you want to use the value of a variable you just use the variable. It helps if you're familiar with Python, because you can use most of Python's string formatting constructs.

So you could write:

```
This is a road length is: {{road_len["%s_%s_%s" % (country, city, street)]}}
```

Or:

```
This is a road length is: {{road_len[country + "_" + city + "_" + street]}}
```

Or:

```
This is a road length is: {{road_len["{}_{}_{}".format(country, city, street)]}}
```

Comment: Great answer! That solved my issue. Thank you!!!